# With a 'man in the middle' attack, can the attacker find out Client/Server session keys with a compromised AS/TGS secret key?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, kerberos

Assuming that an AS/TGS secret key has been compromised by a 'man in the middle' attack who in turn can monitor the network traffic, is an attacker able to find out the Client/Server session keys between clients and services and can they find out which clients are trying to access which services through service ID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a man in the middle was able to get your AS/TGS secret key, then you are doing it wrong.  The entire point of the secret key is that only the TGS knows it and it shouldn't be discoverable.  Preventing a man in the middle attack is the main point of the TGS having a secret key.  If the secret is no longer secret, a man in the middle is possible because the attacker can pretend to be the TGS and you are completely screwed.